# How to apply sum in cakephp join table?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.8

*CakePHP version : 3.8 , database : PostgreSQL*

I have two tables `users` and `transactions`.
transactions table has **foreign key** **user_id**

I am trying to **sum all amount** from transactions table corresponding users. I have tried like

```
$users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');

$query = $users->find();
$query->select([
    'Users.id','Users.email',$query->func()->sum('Transactions.amount')
]) 
->matching('Transactions')
->group(['Users.id']);

$data = $query->all();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo json_encode($value);
}
```

I am getting output like

{"id":72,"email":"test@gmail.com","2":null}
....
....

My desire output

{"id":72,"email":"test@gmail.com","amount":2200}

How can I get my desire result ?

Comment: Is this a simple hasMany association? At minimum probably give the field the name you want, ex: `"amount" => $query->func()->sum('Transactions.amount')`

Comment: yes , hasMany association. And it's worked !!